# CloudFront distribution and AWS issued certificate gives SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I can't get the Internet <-> CloudFront <-> S3 Bucket working, using an AWS certificate. This is what I did:

1. Created a certificate, a wildcard one, like: `*.mydomain.example`.
2. Created a S3 bucket, no fiddeling with properties.
3. Creating a CloudFront distribution, using the created S3 bucket URL as origin, selecting my certificate from step 1, choosing HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0, and choosing HTTP to HTTPS redirect.
4. Created an A alias in my hosted zone for the domain the certificate is issued for, pointing at my distribution URL.

After the distribution is created, my browsers all tell me this:

- Firefox: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
- Chrome: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
- Safari: Can't establish a secure connection.

I'm not sure if I've missed a step in the process of setting this up, I've tried fiddling with various parameters but nothing lets me through.

I read [this blog post](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2016/02/12/how-to-setup-ssl-on-amazon-web-services-with-nginx/), saying that I might have forgotten adding alternate CNAMEs. This confuses me a bit, should I? In Route 53 I configured my full domain using `something.mydomain.example` and the certificate is a wildcard one.

Other blog posts and question answers indicates I should not, just use the A record and the CloudFront distribution URL/endpoint, as I have done.

Comment: I've seen this as a transitory error if you try to access a CloudFront distribution that hasn't finished deploying. Then even after it's fully deployed, FIrefox may continue to show this error for a short while, but it seems to correct itself. If the issue is ongoing there is likely some other cause, as described in the other answers.

Comment: I was getting this error with a Lambda function URL as the CloudFront custom origin.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

So, in my update, I mentioned adding CNAMEs from a blog post. This was it, the second I did that, it started working.

To clarify, I did this to solve my problem:

1. Edit your CloudFront distribution.
2. Under the tab **General**, click edit.
3. In the **Alternate Domain Names** text box, add (at least) the `something.mydomain.example` that you have configured to this distribution's endpoint/URL in Route53.
4. Save your changes.

This solved it instantly for me, but remember that CloudFront configuration changes sometimes can take some time to be pushed out.

Comment: This is not just for alternate names. I had to put ALL names in the CNAMES fields in order for all names to work properly.

Comment: it is not clear. what you mean by `something.mydomain.com that you have configured to this distribution's endpoint/URL in Route53`

Comment: I struggled with this same error and the cause was simply mistyped domain name.

Comment: Thankyou, thankyou, thankyou!!! I was tearing my hair out this weekend!

Comment: It's a bit unintuitive so maybe worth mentioning: this fix appears to address apex domains (example.com) as well - not just subdomains (sub.example.com). At least I found that to be the case for me.

Answer (score 15):

As stated by OP in an edit error caused when a **CNAME** entry for the apex (naked) domain, `www` subdomain, other subdomain or other domain(s) are not listed in the distribution.

[image]

To fix add at least one CNAME to the distribution in CloudFront.

Answer (score 3):

Weird but true:

What actually fixed the issue for me was bumping the minimum cypher version up from `TLSv1` to `TLSv1.1_2016` in the CF Distribution.

Here's the relevant CloudFormation snippet:

```
HttpVersion: "http2"
ViewerCertificate:
  AcmCertificateArn: !Ref SslCertificateArn
  MinimumProtocolVersion: "TLSv1.1_2016"
  SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

Weird because I don't understand why this change fixes anything. The browser should automatically negotiate the higher TLS version.